# Automate Deployment of Docker

Tags: deployment, docker, coreos

I have built my new Docker Image (with my latest code) using CircleCI. Now I want to deploy it to Digital Ocean. I want it to write deployment script.

Docker are running on CoreOS Cluster. I am confused only on the missing link on how to inform my existing CoreOS cluster for the new image. 
What solution is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you need to hook yourself to the registry. Either your private one or the public docker hub.
You can add a hook that will be triggered each time your push a new image. That hook can be a simple http call somewhere in your cluster that will trigger a new `docker pull` & co.